# Show Carousel Images JavaME

Tags: java, carousel

Hi everybody im new in this forum but i see always when im looking for excellent answer so i decided join to this forum well im not good with Java i preffer VB.NET or C# but anyway. I wanna know how i can do something like a carousel of images actually im doing this

```
    Image[] imasDes = new Image[3];

    try {
        imasDes[0] = Image.createImage("/Cusco.jpg");
        imasDes[1] = Image.createImage("/Tumbes.jpg");
        imasDes[2] = Image.createImage("/Piura.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

and when i check an option from choicegroup i go to other form where i can see this images well now my question is if i can show this 3 images but like carousel i mean first i could show the first image and 3 seconds later the second imagn and 3 seconds later the third and again repeat the first images is that possible? im giving my first steps with JavaME i dont know how do this. Thanks

Comment: you need [thread](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) buddy.

Comment: nice resource i will check  this

Comment: well i think your comment solve my question now how i can check your comment like an answer?